# Need some guidance on deploying/hosting a web app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, web-applications

I recently developed a web app locally, with a React frontend that interacts via proxy with a Node.js backend that interacts with MongoDB Atlas. Everything works locally, and I am ready to actually deploy the web app for public use.

How does hosting work with a full stack web application? Do I host the entire web app in the same place (e.g. S3 bucket), or should the backend and frontend be deployed separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have two different servers for frontend and backend.

You can use the [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs) platform to deploy your backend app, and [Mlab](https://mlab.com/) to provision a Mongo database. These platforms has free tiers where you can experiment and learn about deployments and clouds.

Once you are comfortable with these then you can move to Elastic Bean Stalk on AWS to provision servers and also database.

Comment: Ended up deploying on Heroku, with the backend communicating directly with MongoDB Atlas. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! that it worked for you, but make sure you learn every thing that heroku does for you in the backend. Read the documentation, this knowledge you can carry forward to other better platform like Azure, AWS etc.

Comment: Start with Npm hooks!

Answer (score 0):

Now mlab is not available as it is already been acquired by mongoDB only, so I would recommend you to create the database on Atlas cluster which also offers a free tier.

Rather than using the Heroku, I would suggest you to use MongoDB stitch which is also the backend as a service. If you will use stitch then you can also seek for support from mongoDB people but in case you will use heroku then you will not receive any support from them.

You can refer to the documentation of stitch for more information https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/. This has complete guidance how you can deploy your app using stich and can use mongodb database.

Comment: Ended up deploying on Heroku and everything is working smoothly, thanks!